# Ajax POST - get a checkbox value for validation

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'd like to validate a form with ajax where there is a checkbox field.

I tried in this way but I can't get the value of checkbox field.

MY FORM

```
<form class="Form" action="?">

   <input type="text" name="type" id="type" />
   <input type="text" name="action" id="action" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="1">

   <input type="submit" value="INSERT" />

</form>
```

MY AJAX

```
  $(".Form").submit(function( event ) {

   event.preventDefault();

   $.post("control.php", {

    type: $("#type").val(),
    action: $("#action").val(),
    chk: $("#chk").val()
    },

    function(data){

        $("#msg").html(data);

    }
});
```

CONTROL.PHP

```
// CHECKBOX VALUE
if($_POST["chk"] == 1){
   echo "THE VALUE IS 1";
exit;
}
```

How I could Do this? Thanks

EDIT

I tried pass to control page the chk with no success

```
$.post("control.php", {

   type: $("#type").val(),
   action: $("#action").val(),
   chk: $("#chk").prop('checked')
},
```

and

```
 $.post("control.php", {

   type: $("#type").val(),
   action: $("#action").val(),
   $("#chk").prop('checked')
},
```

How can I define the name of my checkbox field in ajax post? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This returns true if the checkbox is checked:

```
$("#chk").prop('checked')
```

And in PHP check it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["chk"])) // true
```

Comment: But can I pass the checkbox to $.post? I tried chk: $("#chk").prop('checked') and $("#chk").prop('checked') but with no success. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

For check boxes, php passing value if only check box selected. so you can check is that check box received to PHP page. if its received user has selected it or if user not selected, no check box name passing to PHP page.

so you can check

if(isset($_POST["chk"]))

...
if this returns true, that means user selected check box and if not user not selected...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you send a zero value with the same name in a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="1">
```

and if chk is checked the hidden input chk will be overriden in the $_POST